# Unable to highlight text in React JS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a react component. The text that is outputted through JSX is not selectable. I want to be able to drag my mouse over the text and have it be copied. Any ideas?

Specifically, I want the `discount_code` to be selectable.

```
<div style={styles.discountContainerCode}>
  <div style={styles.titleRowCode}>
    <div style={styles.discountRowTitle}>Code</div>
  </div>
  <div style={styles.codeRowBox}>
    <div style={styles.code} >{this.state.discount_code}</div>
  </div>
  <div style={styles.codeRowTextContainer}>
    <div style={styles.codeRowText}>
      To redeem your code tap the button below, fill out the <u>Free Qoute Online</u> form and enter your code at checkout.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style={styles.codeRowButton}>
    <div style={styles.codeRowButtonText}>Redeem Code</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have `pointer-events: none` applied somewhere in your CSS?

Comment: I do not. Should I set them up? I am going to research pointer events. I have never used them.

Comment: No, `pointer-events: none` will make your text unselectable. Another CSS rule that may make your text unselectable is `user-select:none`. Without seeing your CSS it's hard to tell.

Comment: Please post the CSS applied to the elements you're experiencing the issue with.  There's no reason the text should not be selectable, unless the CSS has disabled selection as @YoavKadosh suggested or if you're using absolute positioning and there's another element overlapping the text or the z-index is set strangely.

Comment: I just checked my styling and there was a user-select none. Thank you. It works now. My sanity has returned!